Handling events in a relational data warehouse that could be updated in the source
I have to design a table in a data warehouse to store event like 'box access'. The source system works as follows:

An access event is registered by an employee, creating a new record with a unique access ID.

The employee manually updates the access end date when the customer finishes accessing the box. This update can happen several days later if forgotten.


The problem is that sometimes an employee forgots to update access end date and he can update it next day or several days later. Since the source data can change, I need to reflect these changes in the data warehouse. The data warehouse is relational, closer to Inmon approach, not Kimball.
My proposed design is to use technical columns for start date and end date for each access event. If an update occurs in the source, I would close the corresponding row and insert a new row with the same access ID but with updated start and end dates (similar to SCD2).
However, I have doubts about this approach because using record start/end dates for event data seems unusual. Typically, this method is applied to data like products and customers. I'm considering whether it might be better to simply update the record in the data warehouse and add a "last update date" column to track changes.
It's crucial for me to know when records are updated, as I need to send the updated data to other stakeholders.

Are there any arguments against using technical start/end dates for event data like this?
Would it be more appropriate to use a "last update date" column and update the existing record instead?


Hi - have a look at accumulating snapshot fact tables

@NickW Thanks, I'm reading about it right now and it seems that it's just what I've mentioned as a second approach - if an event was updated in the source then update existing record in a data warehouse with the new access end date
